# Wooslider/Flexslider Respnsive Image not working

Tags: image, wordpress, flexslider

I'm making a portfolio site for a client and so getting responsive images to work is important. Before I converted the design to WordPress everything was all working 100% but I just installed the WordPress plugin called Wooslider which is based off the Flexslider. It has some issues with images, blowing them up until they're really pixelated, it keeps expanding the images past the size their saved as.

There are two ways to make a slide with this plugin, one with all the attached images to the post and page or by creating each individual slide (as you do with posts and joining them all up by their category)

I had a play around with the plugin's CSS, and solved the issue with the slide created by the attached images, they had used width: 100% instead of max-width: 100% - I thought this would be the case with another attribute elsewhere, but had no luck so far. I've tried also adding in height: auto in some places and still no luck.

Here're the two CSS codes for the plugin

Flexslider css:

```
    /*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.1
 * http://www.woothemes.com/wooslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 */


/* Browser Resets */
.wooslider-container a:active,
.wooslider a:active,
.wooslider-container a:focus,
.wooslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.wooslider-control-nav,
.wooslider-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* wooslider Necessary Styles
*********************************/ 
.wooslider {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;}
.wooslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.wooslider .slides img {max-width: 100%; display: block;}
.wooslider-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.wooslider .slides:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; } 
html[xmlns] .wooslider .slides { display: block; } 
* html .wooslider .slides { height: 1%; }

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .wooslider .slides > li:first-child { display: block; }


/* wooslider Default Theme
*********************************/
.wooslider {margin: 0 0 60px; background: #fff; border: 4px solid #fff; position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1;}
.wooslider-viewport {max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease;}
.loading .wooslider-viewport {max-height: 300px;}
.wooslider .slides {zoom: 1;}

.wooslider .carousel li {margin-right: 5px}

/* Direction Nav */
.wooslider-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url(../images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; -moz-transition: all .3s ease; -o-transition: all .3s ease; transition: all .3s ease;}
.wooslider-direction-nav .wooslider-next {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }
.wooslider-direction-nav .wooslider-prev {left: -36px;}
.wooslider:hover .wooslider-next {opacity: 0.8; right: 5px;}
.wooslider:hover .wooslider-prev {opacity: 0.8; left: 5px;}
.wooslider:hover .wooslider-next:hover, .wooslider:hover .wooslider-prev:hover {opacity: 1;}
.wooslider-direction-nav .disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}

/* Pause/Play */
.wooslider-pauseplay a  { width: 30px; height: 30px; text-indent: -9999px; background: url(../images/bg_play_pause.png) no-repeat 110% 0; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 9999; cursor: pointer; }
.wooslider-pauseplay a:hover  { opacity: 1; }
.wooslider-pauseplay a.wooslider-play { background-position: 0 0; }

/* Control Nav */
.wooslider-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 100%; margin-top: 10px!important; text-align: center; z-index: 9999; }
.wooslider-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.wooslider-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.wooslider-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.wooslider-control-paging li a.wooslider-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.wooslider-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.wooslider-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.wooslider-control-thumbs img {max-width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.wooslider-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.wooslider-control-thumbs .wooslider-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .wooslider-direction-nav .wooslider-prev {opacity: 1; left: 0;}
  .wooslider-direction-nav .wooslider-next {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
```

Second plugin CSS

```
    .wooslider .slides > li { list-style: none; float: left; }
.wooslider .slides img { max-width: 100%; border: 0; }
body .wooslider.wooslider-type-posts img, body .wooslider.wooslider-type-attachments img { max-width: 100%; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; height: auto; }
body .wooslider .slides, body .wooslider .wooslider-control-nav, body .wooslider .wooslider-direction-nav { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body .wooslider .wooslider-control-nav li, body .wooslider .wooslider-direction-nav li { list-style: none; }

/* Layout styles for the "Posts" slideshow type. */

/* Text Left and Text Right Options */
.wooslider .layout-text-left img { float: right; width: 40%; }
.wooslider .layout-text-left .slide-excerpt { float: left; width: 50%; }

.wooslider .layout-text-right img { float: left; width: 40%; }
.wooslider .layout-text-right .slide-excerpt { float: right; width: 50%; }

/* Full overlay enabled */
.wooslider .overlay-full  { position: relative; }
.wooslider .overlay-full .slide-excerpt { background: #000; opacity: 0.8; color: #FFF; position: absolute; padding: 1em; }
.wooslider .overlay-full .slide-excerpt .slide-title { color: #FFF; }
.wooslider .overlay-full img { float: none; width: 100%; height: auto; }

body .wooslider .overlay-full.layout-text-left .slide-excerpt { left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 30%; padding: 1em; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-full.layout-text-right .slide-excerpt { right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 30%; padding: 1em; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-full.layout-text-top .slide-excerpt { left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; height: auto; padding: 1em; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-full.layout-text-bottom .slide-excerpt { left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: auto; padding: 1em; overflow: hidden; }

/* Natural overlay enabled */
.wooslider .overlay-natural  { position: relative; }
.wooslider .overlay-natural .slide-excerpt { color: #FFF; position: absolute; float: left; padding: 0; }
.wooslider .overlay-natural .slide-excerpt .slide-title { color: #FFF; background: #000; opacity: 0.8; float: left; padding: 0.5em 1em; margin: 0; }
.wooslider .overlay-natural .slide-excerpt p { color: #FFF; background: #000; opacity: 0.8; float: left; padding: 0.5em 1em; }
.wooslider .overlay-natural img { float: none; width: 100%; height: auto; }

body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-left .slide-excerpt { left: 0; top: 10%; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-right .slide-excerpt { float: right; right: 0; top: 10%; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-right .slide-excerpt .slide-title, 
body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-right .slide-excerpt p { float: right; }
body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-top .slide-excerpt { left: 0; top: 0; overflow: hidden; }
body .wooslider .overlay-natural.layout-text-bottom .slide-excerpt { left: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; }

/* "Slides" slideshow type */
body .wooslider .slide-content { margin: 0.5em; padding: 0; border: 0; width: auto; height: auto; }

/* Slide widget */
.widget_wooslider_slideshow_attachments .wooslider-direction-nav a  { padding: 0; }

body .wooslider.wooslider-type-posts img, body .wooslider.wooslider-type-attachments img, body .wooslider.wooslider-type-attachments img { max-width: 100%; border: none; height: auto;}
body .wooslider-control-nav { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body .wooslider-control-nav img { border: 0; background: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body .wooslider-direction-nav, body .wooslider-direction-nav li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body .wooslider.wooslider-type-slides .has-featured-image img.featured-image { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
body .wooslider.wooslider-type-slides img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Comment: I solved it by adding in a new attribute with the following

    .slides img {
    max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; margin: 0 auto;}

it was the width: auto that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The above CSS override provided by ichabod1799 worked perfectly for me.

```
.slides img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears from reading around trying to resolve this issue that at some point flexslider added a style attribute to images containing the height and width of the image, resulting in any CSS aimed at altering the size rendered useless.

I simply added this after the call to initialise flexslider:

```
$(this).find('li img').removeAttr('style');
```

This removes any style attributes from the images, and then the width can be controlled by CSS.

Comment: Where exactly did you add this? Which file? Where in the file?